# nodejs async function parameters durability in rapid calls

Tags: javascript, node.js, zeromq

sorry the topic might be confusing coz i don't know how to say that.

consider a situation that i have a async function with one parameter. an array.

i used this parameter inside function. I'm afraid that calling function multiple times could rewrite the array i sent to function previously. Could it be happened?

assume this code:
//this is an IPC function which will be called by another process.

```
responder.on('message', function(request) {
    resp = msgpack.unpack(request);
    //resp is my array.
    myvar = resp[1];
    .
    .
    .
}
```

I'm afraid resp[] will be overwrite before the first call finished and this cause problem in first call code execution.

Comment: Can you expand on where your "resp" variable is declared, in comparison to the scope of your responder.on function.  This is very important for answering this question.  Right now it appears you have created a global, and assigned it the value of msgpack.unpack(request).

Comment: If "resp" is declared outside the handler function, then it will be shared by all such handlers created in that context (and all invocations). However, it should also be noted that only one invocation of the handler will be active at any one time.

Comment: @Pointy: "Only one invocation of the handler will be active at any one time."  Node provides no such guarantee, and this is precisely what I believe is the OPs concern.

Comment: @ChrisCM ah well if that's the case (and I find that somewhat surprising, as it means that there are a host of potential synchronization problems for which JavaScript provides no facilities), then yes it's a problem.

Comment: @ChrisCM actually I'm finding it hard to locate anything that claims a Node event loop can be preempted by another event.

Comment: Consider an http request handler, that in turn fires this message event.  How many http handlers can be live at once? (hint, it's at least in the hundreds)  Can not each of these handlers emit the 'message' event, and expect it to be processed before the other 'message' handlers finished? (hint the answer is yes)

Comment: @ChrisCM Again, the question is whether one event loop can preempt another. Node.js is not a concurrent system; there aren't any "threads".

Comment: This is not correct.  Node is essentially a wrapper around the V8 C++ engine.  The V8 C++ engine can handle the concurrency that asynchronous javascript provides in any way it deems necessary, including potentially the use of threads, as long as it conforms the the javascript functionality expectations.  Just because at the script level we don't see it happening, doesn't mean that it isn't happening.

Comment: If you would like to discuss how Node functions more, I'd be happy to, but lets do so in discussion, you are unnecessarily polluting this post with inaccurate information and misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following example:

```
function doStuff() {
    var temp = 0;

    function modifyTemp(temp) {
        temp = 5;
    }

    modifyTemp(temp);

    //the value of temp is still 0

    function modifyTemp2() {
        temp = 10;
    }

    modifyTemp2();

    //temp now equals 10
}

doStuff();
```

Notice that temp is within the closure scope of "doStuff()".  So any reference to temp within this scope will use this reference, unless there is one that takes precedence, as in the example of modifyTemp(temp) declaration.  In this case, a temp copy of the temp variable is created and stored to "temp" which is modifed within the scope of only this funciton, and the temp defined within the closure is left untouched.  So the answer to your question is, it depends on what level of scope you have declared your resp variabled.  The way your could looks to be written, I would suggest that what you are concnered about happening is in fact a concern.

The following modifications (provided in commented/uncommented lines) would potentially provide jurastically different behaviors, depending on how the rest of your program function, and how much async stuff you have going on.  Notice that the uncommented implementation redefines the variable, so that we don't need to worry about consecutive runs or other functions interfering with it's value.

```
responder.on('message', function(request) {
    //resp = msgpack.unpack(request);
    var resp = msgpack.unpack(request);
    //resp is my array.
    myvar = resp[1];
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: actually, i used resp only inside this function,not at some parent functions.anyway, i changed my code and defined resp with "var". thank you

Comment: Ah, in this case you created an errant global(not good) and would have been creating this problem unnecessarily, this should therefore be a seamless fix for you!  Good luck!